# Invalid usage of `RuntimeEvent`

Tags: pallet, substrate-node-template

I am a beginner learning the substrate framework, So am actually following the documentation on the substrate website where it references the use of macros in a custom pallet, after implementing all the code, am facing some import errors, due to the lines posted below.

```rs
pub use pallet::*;
#[frame_support::pallet]
pub mod pallet {
    use frame_support::pallet_prelude::*;
    use frame_system::pallet_prelude::*;
```

Below is the complete error trace

```rs
    Compiling pallet-template v4.0.0-dev (/Users/mac/Desktop/pallet-identity/pallets/template)
  error: Invalid usage of RuntimeEvent, `Config` contains no associated type `RuntimeEvent`, but enum `Event` is declared (in use of `#[pallet::event]`). An RuntimeEvent associated type must be declare on trait `Config`.
    --> /Users/mac/Desktop/pallet-identity/pallets/template/src/lib.rs:11:1
     |
  11 | #[frame_support::pallet]
     | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     |
     = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `frame_support::pallet` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

  error[E0432]: unresolved import `pallet`
   --> /Users/mac/Desktop/pallet-identity/pallets/template/src/lib.rs:7:9
    |
  7 | pub use pallet::*;
    |         ^^^^^^ help: a similar path exists: `frame_system::pallet`

  For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0432`.
  error: could not compile `pallet-template` due to 2 previous errors
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outdated
~~Check your `Cargo.toml`. I think you missed the `frame-support` dependency.~~

---

After you updated the detail.

The main error is:

```rs
error: Invalid usage of RuntimeEvent, `Config` contains no associated type `RuntimeEvent`, but enum `Event` is declared (in use of `#[pallet::event]`). An RuntimeEvent associated type must be declare on trait `Config`.
```

So, follow the message to add the `RuntimeEvent` field back to your `Config` trait.

```rs
type RuntimeEvent: From<Event<Self, I>> + IsType<<Self as frame_system::Config>::RuntimeEvent>;
```

---

After taking a look at your source code.

I believe you have updated your Substrate version.

There is a breaking change.

`Config::Event` was renamed to `Config::RuntimeEvent`.

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/11981.

---

```rs
error[E0432]: unresolved import `pallet`
```

This error is because the macro will generate a mod `pallet`. But another error occurred while expending/executing the macro, so the mod `pallet` can not be generated. Thus, it reports can not find the `pallet`

Comment: the frame-support dependency is actually present ```frame-support = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.30" }``` even the frame-system dependency is present too

Comment: ```error[E0432]: unresolved import `pallet` ``` was added to the error trace too.

Comment: Could you put the full error log in the question? If there is a link to the code, that would be much better.

Comment: I just added the error trace and this is a link to the code on github [https://github.com/jim-nnamdi/pallet-identity/blob/main/pallets/template/src/lib.rs ] (github)

Comment: It looks like you updated your Substrate dependencies.

`Config::Event` was renamed to `Config::RuntimeEvent`

Comment: THANKS MAN! you saved a soul